# Changing a JMenuBar border

Tags: java, swing, border, jmenubar

I'm trying to change the border of a JMenuBar with an other border. Like that (for example) :

From [Image 1 http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/696780Sanstitre.png](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/696780Sanstitre.png) 
To [Image 2 http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/900299Sanstitre2.png](http://img11.hostingpics.net/pics/900299Sanstitre2.png)

But I can't find a way to do that. I can change anything I want but that.

[edit]
I have already tried :

```
UIManager.put("Menu.border", BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));
UIManager.put("MenuBar.border", BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));
UIManager.put("MenuItem.border", BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));
```

and it's doesn't worked :( ...

[/edit]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally I found eaxctly what you are looking for :) The right property for the UIManager is `PopupMenu.border`. To change the border of the whole popup menu to a thickness of 4 pixel and a red color (just a funny example) you need the following line:

```
UIManager.put("PopupMenu.border", BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.red, 4));
```

Here is a small example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public class CustomPopupMenuBorder
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        UIManager.put("PopupMenu.border", BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1));      
        JDialog myJDialog = new JDialog();
        myJDialog.setSize(450,300);
        JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("It's a me");
        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem("JMenuItem 1");
        JMenuItem item2 = new JMenuItem("JMenuItem 2");
        menu.add(item);
        JSeparator sep = new JSeparator();    
        menu.add(sep);
        menu.add(item2);
        bar.add(menu);
        myJDialog.setJMenuBar(bar);
        myJDialog.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

The best help I had on my journey to get this is the java application [UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/)

Answer (score 2):

I would start by looking at the [javax.swing.border.Border class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/border/Border.html). Every Swing class which extends [javax.swing.JComponent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) has a [setBorder() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setBorder%28javax.swing.border.Border%29).

I strongly suggest that you familiarize yourself with the [Java API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/). These are an invaluable tool when you are programming in Java.

Comment: I have already checked the java doc conscientiously, but thanks for the advice ;) I think I'm gonna remove the border of every component of Swing until this border disapear.